# Местоположение ссылки на экране

Tags: javascript

На веб-странице имеются ссылки.
Как получить местоположение ссылки (отступ сверху и слева), пользуясь только инструментом разработчика?
А затем сохранить полученные координаты в файл.

Comment: `Element#getBoundingClientRect`.